# Using aluminium foil as a reflection for UV at 240nm

Tags: geometric-optics

Will aluminium foil or sheeting reflect UV light at 240nm being used as a disinfection cell for bacteria in water.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you are asking here. Could you clarify what you intend and what your question is?

Comment: The question seems straightforward - will Al foil reflect UV at 240nm? The answer is "yes". How well depends on how shiny it is. If it is like a mirror it will be very good.